# Post Multiple Forms Data Via Ajax to Single View in Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

i have two forms on a page. 1st is shown and 2nd one is hidden.

1st form shows list of users and their emails in grid and pagination. when i select a multiple users from grid then a div shows up on the right side of the gird. which will be used to send email to selected user.

2nd form that shows up will input email subjects from users and then pass these whole data to django views.

i have user this ajax code to send whole data to the views function.

```
    $("#_send").click(function(){
             var frm = $('#messageform');
                frm.submit(function () {
                var selectedID = [];
   $(':checkbox[name="selectedvalues[]"]:checked').each(function(){
                    selectedID.push($(this).data("email"));
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/sendemail/',
                        processData: true,
                        data: {'frm':frm.serialize(),
                             'selectedID': selectedID},
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                });
        });
```

and in django views i am catching like this;

```
def Send_Message(request):
    checked_items = request.POST.getlist('selectedID[]')
    Msg_Content = str(request.POST.get('content'))
    frm = request.POST.get('frm')
    print checked_items
    print frm
    print Msg_Content
```

**it outputs like this;**

```
abc@gmail.com,abc123@cogilent.comm   

csrfmiddlewaretoken=dP7VkSQdWx0fXuX0kJC46arv6HFElvgz&subject=Hi+This+is+testing+message&content=ddddd
```

but i want these data seperately, message content and message subject.

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize the data; you should be able to do `request.POST.get('subject')` etc